# Помогите прочитать файл и записать его в переменную

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

Пишу приложение с использованием D3. Оно должно строить графики из форм ввода на станице и из файла. С последним у меня проблемы, не могу никак прочитать файл и записать его в переменную. Суть проблемы в том что для чтения использую функцию и значение хранятся в ней, а переменную необходимо будет передавать другим функциям. Прошу помощи. Был Конечно вариант вызова функций из функции чтения но по какой-то причине d3 выдает ошибку.

Благодарю за внимание.

---

Код моей программы.

```
//Добавления строки таблицы

$('.btn').click(function () {
var ind = $('tr:last').index();
$('.hide').clone().appendTo('table').addClass('row').removeClass('hide');
$('tr:last>td:nth-child(2)>input').addClass('x');
$('tr:last>td:nth-child(3)>input').addClass('y');
$('tr:last>td:first').text(ind);
});

var rawData = [];
var z = 0;
var height = 500, 
width = 500, 
margin=30,
data=[];
var numb;

//функция построения графика

var chart1 = function () {
// создание объекта svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

// функция, создающая по массиву точек линии
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d){return d.x;})
    .y(function(d){return d.y;});

// добавляем путь
svg.append("g").append("path")
.attr("d", line(data))
.style("stroke", "steelblue")
.style("stroke-width", 2);
}

//функция построения сетки координат

var osi = function () {
// создание объекта svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("class", "axis")
    .attr("width", width + 10)
    .attr("height", height + 10);

// длина оси X= ширина контейнера svg - отступ слева и справа
var xAxisLength = width - 2 * margin;     

// длина оси Y = высота контейнера svg - отступ сверху и снизу
var yAxisLength = height - 2 * margin;

// функция интерполяции значений на ось Х  
var scaleX = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, numb])
    .range([0, xAxisLength]);

// функция интерполяции значений на ось Y
var scaleY = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([numb, 0])
    .range([0, yAxisLength]);

// масштабирование реальных данных в данные для нашей координатной системы
for(i=0; i<rawData.length; i++)
    data.push({x: scaleX(rawData[i].x)+margin, y: scaleY(rawData[i].y) + margin});

    // создаем ось X   
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scaleX)
    .orient("bottom");
// создаем ось Y             
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(scaleY)
    .orient("left");

for(i=0; i<rawData.length; i++)
    data.push({x: scaleX(rawData[i].x)+margin, y: scaleY(rawData[i].y) + margin});


// отрисовка оси Х             
svg.append("g")       
    .attr("class", "x-axis")
    .attr("transform",  // сдвиг оси вниз и вправо
    "translate(" + margin + "," + (height - margin) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

// отрисовка оси Y 
svg.append("g")       
    .attr("class", "y-axis")
    .attr("transform", // сдвиг оси вниз и вправо на margin
        "translate(" + margin + "," + margin + ")")
    .call(yAxis);

// создаем набор вертикальных линий для сетки   
d3.selectAll("g.x-axis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .classed("grid-line", true)
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", 0)
    .attr("y2", - (yAxisLength));

// рисуем горизонтальные линии координатной сетки
d3.selectAll("g.y-axis g.tick")
    .append("line")
    .classed("grid-line", true)
    .attr("x1", 0)
    .attr("y1", 0)
    .attr("x2", xAxisLength)
    .attr("y2", 0);
}

//функция которая читает значение переменных и записывает из в масив. 
//[{x: 1, y: 2} ,{x: 3, y: 4} ,{x: 5, y: 6} ,{x: 7, y: 8},{x: 9, y: 10}] так должен выглядеть масив чтобы D3 его могла прочитать.

function inputToMass() {
var inpx = $('.x');
var inpy = $('.y');
var x, y;
var massx = [];
var massy = [];
var mass = {};
var cur = 0;
for (i = 0; i < inpx.length; i++) {
    mass = {};
    x = inpx[i].value;
    x = parseInt(x);
    mass.x = x;
    y = inpy[i].value;
    y = parseInt(y);
    mass.y = y;
    rawData[i] = mass;
}
for (i = 0; inpx.length > i; i++) {
    x = inpx[i].value;
    x = parseInt(x);
    massx[i] = x;
    y = inpy[i].value;
    y = parseInt(y);
    massy[i] = y;
}
for (var i = 0; i < massx.length; i++) {
    if (cur < massx[i]) {
        cur = massx[i];
    }
    if (cur < massy[i]) {
        cur = massy[i];
    }
}
var ax = cur/100*7;
numb = cur + ax;
}

// общая функция которая при нажатии на кнопку вызывает остальные функции


$('.btn2').click(function () {
$('svg').remove();
inputToMass();
osi();
chart1()
console.log(rawData);

});

// функция чтения из файла

$('.file').change(function () {
var fr = new FileReader();
fr.onload = function(info) {
var rezf = info.target.result;
rawData = rezf;
return rezf;
}
fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
});
```

---

Код ошибки D3

```
d3.v3.min.js:1 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNL…".
```

---

HTML код

```
    <div class="table">
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>X</th>
            <th>Y</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hide">
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="number"></td>
            <td><input type="number"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="row">
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input class="x" type="number"></td>
            <td><input class="y" type="number"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<br><br>

    <button class="btn">Add Row</button>

    <button class="btn2">generate</button>

    <input class="file" type="file">

    <pre class="cont"></pre>
```

Comment: NaN NaN NaN NaN - скорее всего вы неправильно парсите числа в файле. Возможно, их нужно просто прогнать через parseInt/parseFloat, а может проблема с файлом